# Does Powershell really need an HTML extension and doesn't work with HTM?

Tags: powershell, path, file-extension

I am currently trying to search and replace specific pieces of text in an html file. During this I gave a path to the file which is an HTM file. When I start the script he tells me he cant find the path to XYZ\ABC.htmL... When I change the file extension to HTML the script works perfectly fine.
Was just wondering if there is any way to make PS work with an HTM extension because it would really be quiet annoying changing all the files to htmL.

Thanks in advance!

```
$remBM = ((Get-Content -path Installation_vorbereitung.html -Raw) -replace 'NAME="pgfId.*?"','') | Set-Content -Path Installation_vorbereitung.html
$remBM
```

That's the working version. If I use Installation_vorbereitung.htm it won't work.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What does not work? ... it works for me when I try with a test file. If you get an error post it here. What would you expect as a result? Did you check the content of the file?

Comment: Ok, so I don't know wth was going on but I needed to change the script seperately because he somehow (although he said he saved it....) didn't save it. So now that I adjusted the script with the htm extension while using the htm file it works... sorry for kinda wasting time. I just don't know why he didn't save the changes.

Comment: Don't worry. Sometimes you need to waste some time or to have a second pair of eyes. Cheers.  ;-)